# How to use the Trackbar values correctly in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this simple code in C# that basically implements a blur filter to an image based on the value of a Trackbar in Windows Forms.

```
private void BarraBlur_Scroll_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I take the image inside picture box and use my own Effects class
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Effects foto = new Effects(image);

        switch (BarraBlur.Value)
        {
            case 0:

                pictureBox1.Image = imagens;  // This reestablishes the image to its original state
                break;
            case 1:
                // Each case reestablishes the image to its original state
                // and then applies the blur filter with a given depth
                pictureBox1.Image = imagens;
                pictureBox1.Image = foto.BlurEffect(1);
                break;
            case 2:
                pictureBox1.Image = imagens;
                pictureBox1.Image = foto.BlurEffect(2);
                break;
            case 3:
                pictureBox1.Image = imagens;
                pictureBox1.Image = foto.BlurEffect(3);
                break;
            case 4:
                pictureBox1.Image = imagens;
                pictureBox1.Image = foto.BlurEffect(4);
                break;
            case 5:
                pictureBox1.Image = imagens;
                pictureBox1.Image = foto.BlurEffect(5);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
   }
```

What I want is that, depending on the value of the trackbar whenever it is set, to apply the blur filter to the image. The BlurEffect method takes an *int* argument so that the filter is applied in such value of depth.

The problem is that, if for example, the user sets the trackbar in the *second* position, it works fine, but when it sets it back to the *first* position, instead of returning the image to its original state and then applying the blur filter with depth 1, it applies a blur of depth 1 to the already blurred image with depth 2.

In other words, I want the trackbar to augment the depth of the filter each time the tick goes to the right and diminish the depth of the blur each time the tick of the trackbar goes left.

I have tried this with switch cases and if statements, but neither have worked.

Thanks a lot in advance.

This is the `Effects` class with the BlurEffect method.

```
    class Effects
{
    private Bitmap imagen;

    // Constructor
    public Effects(Bitmap item)
    {
        imagen = item;
    }
public Bitmap BlurEffect(int depth)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < depth; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < imagen.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j < imagen.Height; j++)
                {

                    try
                    {

                        Color antX1 = imagen.GetPixel(i - 1, j);
                        Color antX2 = imagen.GetPixel(i - 2, j);

                        Color desX1 = imagen.GetPixel(i + 1, j);
                        Color desX2 = imagen.GetPixel(i + 2, j);

                        Color antY1 = imagen.GetPixel(i, j - 1);
                        Color antY2 = imagen.GetPixel(i, j - 2);

                        Color desY1 = imagen.GetPixel(i, j + 1);
                        Color desY2 = imagen.GetPixel(i, j + 2);


                        int promR = (int)((antX1.R + antX2.R + desX1.R + desX2.R + antY1.R + antY2.R + desY1.R + desY2.R + imagen.GetPixel(i, j).R) / 9);
                        int promG = (int)((antX1.G + antX2.G + desX1.G + desX2.G + antY1.G + antY2.G + desY1.G + desY2.G + imagen.GetPixel(i, j).G) / 9);
                        int promB = (int)((antX1.B + antX2.B + desX1.B + desX2.B + antY1.B + antY2.B + desY1.B + desY2.B + imagen.GetPixel(i, j).B) / 9);


                        imagen.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(promR, promG, promB));


                    }

                    catch (Exception) { }
                }
            }
        }

        return imagen;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Foto` is just a special image effects object, but it's essentially a Bitmap object.

Comment: OK, well this line `pictureBox1.Image = foto.BlurEffect(5);` is not (OK, very unlikely to be) taking into account the current value of `pictureBox1.Image` - so resetting it to `imagens` before doing the BlurEffect thing is not doing anything. The question is, what class is `foto`, and how does the `BlurEffect()` method work? Does it apply the blur to the underlying bitmap and then return it, or return a *copy* with the blur effect applied? Sounds like it might be the former.

Comment: Ok, so I made a class called `Effects` that has a property `image` of `Bitmap` type. Each method of the class is a different effect on the image, or filter. `BlurEffect` takes `image` and uses pixel averaging to blur the image, then returns `image`, which is of `Bitmap` type. I have implemented a trackbar to make it much more user friendly to blur the image. So I'm using the values of the trackbar for the switch cases, in order to augment or reduce the blurring in the image.

Comment: OK, `Effects` never makes a copy of `image`? So, once you've called `Blur` once, the `Effects` object no longer has an unblurred image to work with.

Comment: Alright, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need the big switch with the repeated code. You can reduce your code to this:

```
if (BarraBlur.Value = 0)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = imagens;  // This reestablishes the image to its original state
}
else {
    pictureBox1.Image = foto.BlurEffect(BarraBlur.Value);
}
```

However, this won't fix your problem. I don't know what class `foto` is, but it *sounds* like it is a wrapper for a Bitmap, and the `BlurEffect()` function applies a blur effect to that bitmap, before returning it. Your code appears to be written with the assumption that `BlurEffect` returns a blurred *copy* of the bitmap.

You can probably fix your code by changing it to construct a new `foto` every time you change the blur:

```
if (BarraBlur.Value = 0)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = imagens;  // This reestablishes the image to its original state
}
else {
    var blur = new Foto(imagens);   // or however the foto is constructed
    pictureBox1.Image = blur.BlurEffect(BarraBlur.Value);
}
```

Since you've indicated that you wrote/control the `foto` class (named `Effects`), you could also change how that class works (instead of doing the above).

Sounds like currently it looks something like:

```
class Effects
{
    private Bitmap _image;

    public Effects(Bitmap image)
    {
        _image = image;
    }

    public Bitmap Blur(int amount)
    {
        // .. code to perform blur on _image ..
        return _image;
    }
}
```

And you should probably change it to be more like:

```
class Effects
{
    private Bitmap _image;

    public Effects(Bitmap image)
    {
        _image = image;
    }

    public Bitmap Blur(int amount)
    {
        var copy = _image.Clone();
        // .. code to perform blur on copy ..
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, precisely that's how I have written the class; I have added some more code regarding the class, but Visual Studio says that "object" (referring to `copy`) does not contain a definition for `GetPixel` and so on, which are `Bitmap` methods.

Comment: It was just a casting mistake, but your solution solved my problem. Thank you very much!!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
pictureBox1.Image = imagens;    
if (BarraBlur.Value == 0) return;
pictureBox1.Image = foto.BlurEffect(BarraBlur.Value);
```

Above replaces your whole code. Your problem is withing `BlurEffect` method. For that reason whenever you use 0 it will work because you will return image to the original. You need to reload image to the original as well at the start of `BlurEffect` method instead of what I'm guessing reusing picture.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The syntax is a bit off, I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2015 and it tells me that this is invalid syntax.

Comment: fixed above, also I'm not sure if it said above you shouldn't have empty catch. Add a log, or throw exception.